# Change total labels in a quote generator CPQ

Tags: quote, cpq, quote-template

In Salesforce CPQ, I can't seem to get rid of the "Ongoing Monthly total" and "Ongoing monthly total VAT", in my yearly quote, I've managed to change the layout and adjust everything to yearly except for this.

Does anyone know where that one lives so that it says "Total Monthly VAT" and "Net Total"

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please add few more details on CPQ software in use and if templates generated natively or using third party tools like Conga?

Comment: This template is generated using the native quote template tool.

Answer (score 3):

`Net Total (SBQQ__NetTotal__c)` is available in Quote Line object (`SBQQ__QuoteLine__c`).

I think, `Total Monthly VAT` is custom field created in this object.

Also, refer `Line Editor` tab under Setting Editor (Install packages->Configure) on how totals has been defined at your org.

[image: Configure]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Line Column record's Column Heading field that controls the display text on the Quote Document.

Answer (score 0):

Greg, you are saying `This template is generated using the native quote template tool` - do you mean standard quote templates available in Sales Cloud? If yes, in this case you go to Setup and search for Quote Templates, then find your template and click Edit next to it. You will see the layout with fields, edit it.

If you're using Salesforce CPQ app, which comes from AppExchange, then all template contents are stored in `Template Content` object. You can find the Template you're utilizing under `Quote Templates` tab, then go to related lists and look through Template sections. One of the sections should use the Template Content that you want to edit.